# IE height 100% incorrect after div removal

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer

If i add a green div of a certain height to my page then scroll-bars are added, as expected. When i remove the div the scroll-bars disappear in all browsers but remain in IE and a white void takes the place of the div, somehow the div height is not recalculated correctly after the removal.

Please see this fiddle for a live demo, you will see that it works in all browsers except in IE.

http://jsfiddle.net/nzbrg/16/

The problem seems to be resolved when removing the `overflow:scroll` for html tag rule, unfortunately this is not an option.
I tested this in latest versions of IE, Chrome and FF and Opera.

Why is this happening and how can i force IE to display the correct height after the dom insertion ?

Note that when you resize the window the white void space disappears immediately, so i just need a way for this to happen without actually re-sizing the window.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that when IE renders a height at 100%, if it grows it will stay the largest size as that is now it's new 100%.  To make it shrink again, instead of giving it a height, you need to give it a min-height  - change your html and body css to

```
body, html {min-height:100%;}
```

this should make your wrapper resize after the green block is removed:

http://jsfiddle.net/nzbrg/6

**EDIT**

The only way I have found to make ie re-render the page is to set the overflow property on the html:

```
$('html').css('overflow', 'auto');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nzbrg/13/

Comment: this works well, however, i can not use min-heigth because one div has to stretch all the way down, in my actual setup. which requires html and body to have 100% height. I really just need a way to force ie to reflow the window. Note that the reflow does occur when re-sizing the window

Comment: Great, that does work to. Unfortunately i can't use that ether, like pointed out in my post, i can't change the overflow because the scroll bar needs to be there in order to prevent the screen from changing width when the scroll-bar appears.

Comment: the scroll bars should stay there with `overflow:auto` - if you look at the fiddle you should still see the scroll bars after the green box has gone

Comment: they are not there when there even if there is nothing to scroll in the beginning.

Comment: sorry, `auto` means that scrollbars will only appear if the content inside the element is overflowing so if your screen is too large to need scrollbars, they will not show

Answer (score 0):

Add `$('body').css('height', 0);`

http://jsfiddle.net/nzbrg/4/

Comment: this works but obviously the height needs to remain 100% if i add `$('body').css('height', "100%");` right after your line of code nothing happens

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this problem by animating the dom insertion and removal ( needs to be both ) with jQuery, this solution only works because i can use an animation off course.

<strike>I don't think this will work if you turn of animation</strike>

I would love to find a better solution, but currently this is going to be it. It looks better with the animation anyway so it's win-win ( for me at least ) :)

see here:
http://jsfiddle.net/nzbrg/15/

```
$("#spacer").slideDown();
$("#spacer").slideUp();
```

**Sneaky Update:**

If you disable animation with `$.fx.off = true;` then it seems to work to. Might have something to do with the way that the animation fumble with the styles to hide and show the div instead of just plain removing it.

Strange because i did also try to hide the element before removing it but was unsuccessful.
Anyway i'm sticking with the animations.